# Windows container BSOD its host

Tags: docker, windows-container, nano-server

We have been using windows containers as test rigs for while now with great success.  However since the last windows update, the container seems it crashes the host system (Windows Server 2019 std).

The server will be running fine for hours, then minutes after executing one of these commands it will crash.

- docker run -it --rm -p 8000:80 --name core_sample  mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:aspnetapp
- docker run --name test  mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809

Just wondering if anybody else is experiencing the same? We already tried to reinstall the host but no joy.

[image: BSOD]

Comment: that is odd, is your docker up to date?

Comment: try using another operating system on your host such as Ubuntu server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going on @cael-ras idea of trying a Ubuntu container, I installed HyverV and is now running my containers in Hyper-V isolation mode (`--isolation=hyperv`) instead of process mode. That seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/hyperv-container